# Doing 198-43 in BCD

Tags: math, arithmetic-expressions, bcd

To solve this I took the 10s complement of 43, which is 57. Then I tried to add the BCD values of 57 and 198 like this:

[image]

The right answer is 155 but I got 255. Pretty sure the carry is the problem. I'm not sure what to do with the carry. I've seen in examples that it is discarded but those examples were only for 1 digit operands. When I did that with larger digit operands it was missing the carry. Maybe I am supposed to discard it only with the leftmost operands?

Help

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: @KenWhite Where should I post this?

Comment: "10s complement of 43, which is 57" - it isn't, since you're dealing with 3-digit numbers.

Comment: I can't tell you that, I'm afraid. All I can tell you is that if it doesn't involve programming (code) or use of a programmers tool (IDE, compiler, etc.), it's not appropriate here.

Comment: @KenWhite it relates to adding BCD numbers

Comment: @phuclv: So? It does not relate to code, because the poster is not writing code to do so.

Comment: @harold is right (and his comment should be an Answer) if you use 3 digit arithmetics then the complement must be 3 digit too ... `1000-43 = 957` so `957+198 = 1|155` which is correct

Comment: @harold Solved, thanks! Your answer didn't click until Spektre replied though